# Azure DevOps API vso:code scope for listing projects

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I want an Azure DevOps token that would be able to

- list Projects of the organization
- list Repositories of each project

From the documentation, it seems that the [`vso.project` scope is required](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP#scopes). However, I've been able to list projects with only the `vso.code` scope, as if the code scope is included in the project scope although I didn't read any documentation confirming that.

Is the "project" scope required to list projects when the token already has the "code" scope?

FYI here is the [list of possible scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops#scopes).

Answer (score 1):

I have tested on your scenario. A token with vso.code scope would have
enough permission to list the following:

> list Projects of the organization
> list Repositories of each project

When creating the token with scope selected:

[image]

Clicking the code(Read), the User profile(Read) turns unable to select.

[image]

For both DevOps PAT and OAuth, the Code(read) permission could return the results of Project and Repos correctly.

Comment: What is bugging me is that this is not official, there is nothing explaining this behavior in the documentation.

Comment: Seems like thats the standard for MS documentation now, its getting more and more difficult to work with incomplete documentation.